# how to call parent div tag but no id and class?

Tags: jquery, html

I have img common class

```
<div debug-id="slide-0" style="width: 800px; height: 356px; top: 0px; left: -800px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
<img class="commonclass" u="image" id="imgid_1" src="upload/img_1.jpg" border="0" style="width: 800px; height: 356px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute;"></div>
```

img class name is all same but div debug-id is different so how to call parent div of style left

```
<div debug-id="slide-1" style="width: 800px; height: 356px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
<img class="commonclass" u="image" id="imgid_2" src="upload/img_2.jpg" border="0" style="width: 800px; height: 356px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute;"></div>
```

and more

```
<div debug-id="slide-2" style="width: 800px; height: 356px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
<img class="commonclass" u="image" id="imgid_3" src="upload/img_2.jpg" border="0" style="width: 800px; height: 356px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute;">
```

Comment: call parent div of style left
?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to select the parent div despite it not having the ID and class selectors available, just select the image and use parent() as below:

```
$('img.commonclass').parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get parent div from attribute `debug-id`,

```
$('*[debug-id="slide-0"]').parent()
```